# Parse JSON and store data in Python Class

Tags: python, json, class

This is my JSON data

```javascipt
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"abc",
        "phone": "12345",
        "Charecteristics": [
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"Good Looking",
                "rating": "Average",
            }
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"Smart",
                "rating": "Excellent",
            }
        ]
    },
    { ... },
    { ... }
]
```

I have two Classes in Python

```
class Character(object):
    id = 0
    name = ""
    rating = ""

class Person(object):
    id = 0
    name = ""
    phone = ""
    Characteristics = []
```

I need to parse the JSON data and instantiate appropriate Classes. The Classes are self-explanatory: i.e. Person has an array of Character classes.

How do I instantiate these and store data appropriately?

Also, how will I access particular Person data? i.e. Person's details and characteristics

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847399/convert-a-json-string-to-python-object

Comment: Note that your JSON example is rather malformed. Apart from the odd quotes you've used, you cannot have multiple `Character` keys in the `Charecteristics` object either.

Comment: I've cleaned up your JSON to actually be valid; note that I've turned both the group of persons and group of characteristics into lists (as they would normally be).

Comment: @Tichodroma: I'll surely do more research the next time.. Sorry I didnt find the similar question at my first few tries.

Comment: See [JSON data into a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object/66054047#66054047)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/); it makes turning a JSON data structure into Python objects dead easy.

You define a schema:

```
import colander


class Characteristic(colander.MappingSchema):
    id = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Int(),
                             validator=colander.Range(0, 9999))
    name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    rating = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())        


class Characteristics(colander.SequenceSchema):
    characteristic = Characteristic()


class Person(colander.MappingSchema):
    id = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Int(),
                             validator=colander.Range(0, 9999))
    name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    phone = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    characteristics = Characteristics()


class Data(colander.SequenceSchema):
    person = Person()
```

then pass in your JSON data structure using the following:

```
deserialized = Data.deserialize(json.loads(json_string))
```

Comment: Thanks.. :-)
I'm new to Python but have to work with web services,, so using dJango.. 
Pls consider me amateur..
One more question..

Comment: Thats not dead easy. Dead easy would be if it generated python classes given a particular JSON string.

Comment: @Vanuan anything that does that?

Comment: @Jonathan The closest is this https://github.com/cwacek/python-jsonschema-objects But it still requires specifying types for each field.

Comment: Thanks @Vanuan, it looks really promising!

Answer (score 6):

If you are writing in python 3.6+, the easiest is probably to use [marshmallow-dataclass](https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass) :

```py
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Character:
    id : int
    name : str
    rating : str

@dataclass
class Person:
    id : int
    name : str
    phone : str
    characteristics : List[Character]

my_person = Person.Schema().loads(json_str)
```