# how to convert json to python class?

Tags: python, json

I want to Json to Python class.

example

```
{'channel':{'lastBuild':'2013-11-12', 'component':['test1', 'test2']}}

self.channel.component[0] => 'test1'
self.channel.lastBuild    => '2013-11-12'
```

do you know python library of json converting?

Comment: [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: See [JSON data into a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object/66054047#66054047)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `object_hook` special parameter in load functions of json module:

```
import json

class JSONObject:
  def __init__( self, dict ):
      vars(self).update( dict )

#this is valid json string
data='{"channel":{"lastBuild":"2013-11-12", "component":["test1", "test2"]}}'

jsonobject = json.loads( data, object_hook= JSONObject)

print( jsonobject.channel.component[0]  )
print( jsonobject.channel.lastBuild  )
```

This method have some issue, like some names in python are reserved. You can filter them out inside `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

the `json` module will load a Json into a list of maps/list. e.g:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

If you want to deserialize into a Class instance, see this SO thread: [Parse JSON and store data in Python Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370498/parse-json-and-store-data-in-python-class)