# split a string into a json object

Tags: python, json

When I extract some data from a data-source the data is getting extracted as a string object and the json is being exported as a string.

I have tried

`json.loads()` -> link1 [Convert string to JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577632/convert-string-to-json-in-python)
and
this [convert a json string to python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847399/convert-a-json-string-to-python-object)
from other answers.

However, the expectation is

```
"details": 
"{
'col1': 'col1_details',
'col2': 'col2_details',
'col3': 'col3_details'
}"
```

the expected outcome is

```
details":
{
'col1': 'col1_details',
'col3': 'col2_details',
'col3': 'col3_details'
}
```

as you see the extra quotes are causing the json to be read as a string and json.loads() and json.dumps() are not working.

I am open to any suggestions without using regex to create a json object directly/easily?

edit:

modified the string object - and the whole point as you see is that the data extraction process is creating a string instead of creating a json object bypassing an extra "" that makes it an invalid json object where I cannot use json.loads and json.dunps and hence the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577632/convert-string-to-json-in-python)

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.  Make a [mcve].  What is the *exact* content of the data object?

Comment: No. It does not. I already tried that solution.

Comment: @Vyas your expected output is not a valid JSON format

Comment: Invalid JSON. Please first verify JSON with a validator. Also, this question just presents some output, without giving the **input**. Not really that handy... You also seem to have two different expectations.

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]. What, *exactly* are your inputs? "When I extract some data from a data-source the data is getting extracted as a string object and the json is being exported as a string." doesn't really make sense, it isn't clear what is going on precisely. Please take the time to create a properly specified question

Comment: So, you are dumping the string representation of a Python `dict` as the value of the `"details"` key (again, you **really** should provide a [mcve], still, currently, you do not have valid JSON anywhere). Then presumably you serialize that outer dict, and that string value is serialized as a JSON string. When you deserialize it, that value is a Python `str`. To get that back, you can use `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval` if you don't trust the source). But you **really** should fix whatever process is creating this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant

```
"details": {
  'col1': 'col1_details',
  'col3': 'col2_details',
  'col3': 'col3_details'
}
```

Then re-loads the data

```
data["details"] = json.loads(data["details"])
```

But, this assumes whatever response you've gotten actually returns valid JSON, which single-quotes are not (there might be a good reason it is returned as a string instead)

Therefore, the most reasonable solution would be to modify the code that returned that response, not try to fix it via parsing it at a later point.

Comment: that's probably not going to work because `data["details"]` seems to be a Python `repr` not a JSON

Comment: well, it isn't the *only* solution, you can `eval` the string back to a Python object, since it seems simple enough

Comment: Or `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: sure, either one would work (assuming the OP's example data is representative of the actual data)